# iPhone: how to make a expandable button (like popup)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I want to make a button which while expand after clicking, and expand to contain my table-view in it. Like [quick graph application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-graph-your-scientific/id292412367?mt=8)

[image: not-expanded]

[image: expanded]

In this application it expands with animation

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to create the button using a **core graphics** OR simply use **two images** for the button states.

Comment: Yes I tried to add two images and then revealing my table view. But how do i put boarder around both table-view and button?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is on the `UIButton` click reveal the `UITableView` in animation. Plus change the `UIButton` image to the down arrow image. This can be done simply. Also according to the image you have shown, do you really need a tableview ? I think you can make a `UIView` and put a `UILabel` in it also. Just think about it . Any further queries or code help needed kindly reply :)

For adding the border use

```
 Table.layer.borderWidth = 10;
 Table.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];

 Button.layer.borderWidth = 10;
 Button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
```

Comment: Yes I tried to add two images and then revealing my table view. But how do i put boarder around both table-view and button?

Comment: See my edited post , in this you will have to import the <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> framework ....

Comment: this will create separate border I want combined border around both of them. So that It looks like expeded

Comment: Then add a UIView around them with a thick border, That will serve ur purpose, make sure to reduce the alpha of the UIView to keep the background of it a bit transparent acc to ur requirement ...